# Can I safely ignore: "warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input"?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, null

Is it possible to safely ignore the aforementioned error message? Or is it possible to remove the null byte? I tried removing it with `tr` but I still get the same error message.

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

monitordir="/home/user/Monitor/"                                                
tempdir="/home/user/tmp/"                                                       
logfile="/home/user/notifyme"                                                   

inotifywait -m -r -e create ${monitordir} |                                     
while read newfile; do                                                          
    echo "$(date +'%m-%d-%Y %r') ${newfile}" >> ${logfile};                     
    basefile=$(echo ${newfile} | cut -d" " -f1,3 --output-delimiter="" | tr -d '\n');
    cp -u ${basefile} ${tempdir};                                               
done
```

when I run `inotify-create.sh` and I create a new file in `"monitordir"`

I get:

```
[@bash]$ ./inotify-create.sh 
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
./inotify-create.sh: line 9: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Comment: Not an answer, but instead of using `echo ... | tr -d '\n'`, why not use `echo -n ...`?

Comment: it's the `--output-delimiter=""` part of your `cut` invocation that's generating the null bytes, are you able to use a different delimiter? And besides to rid null bytes you need `tr -d '\0'` and not `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: You could possibly change the `cut` to `awk '{ print $1$2$3 }'`, but I don't know what your input looks like. You also don't need to end every statement with `;`. You only need to do that if two statements are written on the same line.

Comment: i need --output-delimiter="" because otherwise i get a space in between the directory and filename. The variable $newfile outputs `/home/user/Monitor/ CREATE newfile` with a newline at the end. What about `basefile=$(echo ${newfile} | gawk -F " " '{print $1$3}')`? Any reason not to use gawk (ie speed)?

Comment: @jes516, in that case your `read` should be `while read -r dir _ file` and `basefile` then becomes `${dir}${file}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your exact question:

> Can I safely ignore: “warning: … ignored null byte … ”?

The answer is yes, since you are creating the null byte with your own code.
But the real question is: Why do you need a "null byte"?

The `inotifywait` command will produce an output in the form of:

```
$dir ACTION $filename
```

Which, for your input, looks like this (for file hello4):

```
/home/user/Monitor/ CREATE hello4
```

The command cut will print fields 1 and 3, and using a null delimiter in `--output-delimiter=""` will produce an output with an embedded null, something like:

```
$'/home/user/Monitor/\0hello4\n'
```

That is not what you need, because of the added null.

The solution turns out to be very simple.
Since you are using the command `read` already, do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
monitordir="/home/user/Monitor/"
tempdir="/home/user/tmp/"
logfile="/home/user/notifyme"

inotifywait -m -r -e create ${monitordir} |
    while read dir action basefile; do
        cp -u "${dir}${basefile}" "${tempdir}";
    done
```

Use the default value of IFS to split on whitespace the input and just use the directory and filename to copy.

Comment: this is even better. now the man page makes sense `watched_filename EVENT_NAMES event_filename` aka `dir action file` ty